# How to secure token in case of a redirect from backend to frontend

Tags: rest, api, security, authentication, asp.net-core

### Scenario

**A**-> 3rd Patry SMAL, domain-xyz.com

**B**-> My App-Backend (.net core REST API), domain-b.com

**C**-> My App-Frontend (react app), domain-c.com

when a user tries to login in **C**, redirected to **A** and after authentication, a token is issued by **B**, and the token is added in the URL to **C**, redirect is issued from **B** to **C**.

It shows up the URL in **C** like **domain-c.com/user_access_token**, and this token is used to consume APIs from **B**.

**Problem:**
A visible token in URL is a concern, reported by security testers

**Question:**
how to change it to make this model secure?

please suggest, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The flow which you are talking about is called implicit grant flow where you directly get the token in your front-end. In your case *response type* will be `token`.

Now the question is how to make it more secure. I suggest that instead of response type as `token` you should make it response type `code`.

This will give you a authorization code on the front-end (instead of access_token) which will be useless for hacker who's trying to steal your token.

**Now this code is received at C and you send it to your backend B.**

Do a authorization call to A now with `client_id, client_secret` and received `code` to get the `access token`. Using this access token create a session for the user.

For more information refer: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/10/oauth-authorization-code-grant-type#the-authorization-code-flow